# Is there a way to make this chain of async read and writes more legible

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, metaprogramming

My `session` enables `shared_from_this` to make it possible to call `boost::async_write` and `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::async_read` before an object destruction. The problem is that when I want to chain some `async_write` and `async_read` functions, to create a state machine, the code gets ugly:

```
template <typename ArrType, std::size_t N> inline decltype(auto) boost_buf(ArrType (&arr)[N])
{
    return boost::asio::buffer(arr, N);
}

...
// Inside session class
async_write(socket, boost_buf(header), [self = shared_from_this()](boost_err_code ec,
                                                                            std::size_t /* len */) {
    if (!ec)
        self->socket.async_read_some(boost_buf(self->data), [self = std::move(self)](boost_err_code ec,
                                                                                     std::size_t /* len */) {
            if (!ec)
                async_write(
                    self->socket, boost_buf(respons1),
                    [self = std::move(self)](boost_err_code ec, std::size_t /* len */) {
                        if (!ec)
                            self->socket.async_read_some( ...
```

Is there a way to transform this to something like that:

```
a_write(header, ()[] {
    a_read_into(buf, ()[] {
        a_write(response1, ...
```

I could use `bind` function and for each lambda create a `private` method, but I would like to have the state machine visible within one scope which fits in my screen. I don't care about the content of the response.

I've been trying to figure out `a_write` and `a_read_into` to look like this:

```
template <typename F>
void a_write(   tcp::socket &socket, 
                const std::string &data,
                std::shared_ptr<mbarx_echo_mock_session> &&session,
                F && f );
```

but the problem arises when chaining the second function.

Comment: No, I haven't. I'm going to try that. Thank You